# Client unable to get TCP communication with Server on a VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, tcp, virtualbox

Client is attempting to connect to a Server on a VM

VM is using a bridged adapter

Server CAN ping Client

Client CAN ping server

Wireshark shows a SYNC from Client to Server followed by 2 TCP Retransmissions

It looks like the SYNC is sent to the VM but it's never received.

When the bridged adapter is selected I can surf the web and download files from the web. But when trying to `sudo apt install` applications the output just sits on connecting... and never connects.

But when I power off my machine, add another network adapter of type NAT I am able to `sudo apt install` applications.

In the network advanced tab for bridged I have promiscuous mode - "allow all"

What could cause this type of behavior?

Comment: Windows firewall status on both machines?

Comment: Client has no firewalls and the VM, ubuntu is whatever comes standard. Didn't think Ubuntu was very restrictive when it comes to firewall default settings... I can look into it on the VM